# Hardware for Prototyping a Works-With-Nest Device

Tags: nest-api

does anyone know of a hardware platform that is appropriate to use in prototyping a device that has the ambition to become WWN? I have looked at Proton/Spark-Core, but is there something out there that may be more appropriate/compatible with the Nest-API? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you urman. I'll look into all of those possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Basically anything that can run a web service. All you'll need to do is make an HTTP GET and PUT over HTTPS. More advanced things like Firebase and REST Streaming can still be easily done with a Raspberry Pi. I'm pretty sure an Arduino with a mini-web server can handle GETS and PUTS.